# Filtrado en ComboBox en VB.NET y SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos en SQL Server y estoy haciendo las inserciones y actualizaciones hacia la base de datos usando las sintaxis de SQL Server.

La petición es, si alguien me puede proporcionar un código de cómo hacer un filtrado de una tabla a un `ComboBox` y conforme el usuario vaya escribiendo el nombre se muestren las concidencias, con solo tener el código de uno me basta, con que solo me filtre el nombre me basta, porque los apellidos los tengo en campos diferentes.

Comment: lo que necesitas es usar la seleccion del combo para filtrar una tabla (mediante una query), o quieres implementar el autocomplete en el combobox ?

Comment: Quieres implementar algo así ? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Una opción que tienes es bindar el combobox a los datos de la tabla y en el combobox asignar las propiedades: AutocompleteMode = Suggest y AutocompleteMode = ListItmes de esta manera se cargará la lista completa desde la tabla al control y estará disponible para selección y permitirá escribir en el control e ir recibiendo sugerencias en base a lo escrito.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción que tienes es "bindear" el combobox a los datos de la tabla y en el combobox asignar las propiedades: `AutocompleteMode = Suggest` y `AutocompleteMode = ListItmes` de esta manera se cargará la lista completa desde la tabla al control y estará disponible para selección y permitirá escribir en el control e ir recibiendo sugerencias en base a lo escrito:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim ListaItems As New List(Of String)

        ListaItems.Add("Oveja")
        ListaItems.Add("Ornitorinco")
        ListaItems.Add("Toro")
        ListaItems.Add("Pato")
        ListaItems.Add("Tiranosaurio")
        ListaItems.Add("Piraña")

        Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = ListaItems
        Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems 


        ''' TODO: Reemplazar ListaItems por origen de datos

        ComboBox1.DataSource = ListaItems
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems

        Me.Controls.Add(ComboBox1)

        ComboBox1.Show

    End Sub

End Class
```